# Is there a way to programmatically set up security rules for a custom storage bucket in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

For multiple business and technical reasons, we want to give a specific bucket to each company that use our solution. This bucket is created by a Cloud function triggered by the company registration.

To be used with Firebase, this bucket must be "imported" in the web console in order to define a default security policy that needs to be adjusted.

As we won't be able to do that manually in the long range, is there any possibility to programmatically realize this bucket import and policy enforcement in the Admin SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `admin.securityRules()` API:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#use_the_admin_sdk
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.securityRules.SecurityRules

Comment: Thanks, I was about to answer my own question, having found this well hidden part of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple tests, Im sad to say that even if one is able to create a new bucket with the Admin SDK, there is no way to use it on the client side without manually importing it via the Firebase console.

The security rules can't be added just after creation with the following code. The bucket can't be found by the Admin SDK (`Error: Requested entity was not found.`)

```js
[...]
const bucketName = getCompanyBucketName(key)
const storage = new Storage()
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName)
const result = await bucket.create({ location: 'EU' })
if (result[0]) {
   const ruleset = `
      service firebase.storage {
         match /b/{bucket}/o {
            match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
            }
         }
      }
   `
   await admin
      .securityRules()
      .releaseStorageRulesetFromSource(ruleset, bucketName)
   }
```